# Remove a field inside of array object -javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

This is my response data:

```
var data = [{
            'id': '1',
            'name': 'kamal',
            'age': '21'
        }, {
            'id': '2',
            'name': 'ram',
            'age': '11'
        }, {
            'id': '3',
            'name': 'karuna',
            'age': '22'
        }, ];
```

I getting this data in to  my response data.
I need to remove field id inside of object.
I want to splice the **id** field in each object .

expected result is:

```
var data = [{
            'name': 'kamal',
            'age': '21'
        }, {
            'name': 'ram',
            'age': '11'
        }, {
            'name': 'karuna',
            'age': '22'
        }, ];
```

Comment: Have you tried anything, options of the top of my head `map` or if mutated, `delete`..

Comment: Just loop through and use the information from the linked question's answers to remove the property from each object. (Or create new objects without the `id` property if you're doing the immutable thing, but you'e said "remove" and "splice" suggesting you're happy to mutate [modify] the original objects.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through your array and delete every `id` property.

```js
var data = [{
  'id': '1',
  'name': 'kamal',
  'age': '21'
}, {
  'id': '2',
  'name': 'ram',
  'age': '11'
}, {
  'id': '3',
  'name': 'karuna',
  'age': '22'
}, ];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  delete data[i].id;
}

console.log(data);
```